# Interpolating a string in c#

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I want to use string interpolation for the below:

```
payloadArgs = string.Format("{0}TrackingID: \"{1}\"", payload.ToString().Replace("\n", "; "), trackingId);
```

I have tried

```
payloadArgs = $"{trackingId} TrackingId, \"{payload.ToString().Replace("\n", "; "), trackingId};
```

but I am obviously getting it wrong as I am getting a compile error "Cannot implicitly convert a string to int" over the "trackingId" and a warning about "newline in constant"

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: what type is `trackingId`?

Comment: @LeiYang: sorry, trackingId is a string passed in

Comment: What is `payload` and why are you calling `ToString().Replace("\n", "; ")` on it? If it's a number, it won't contain newlines. The code you posted has nothing to do with *ints* anyway. Post a *reproducible* example

Comment: this `{payload.ToString().Replace("\n", "; "), trackingId}` < there is a comma in there that wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. You changed the order between the variables, you had `trackingId` as the first variable instead as the second. In addition, string interpolation doesn't receive parameters in the structure of `(string, parameter, parameter)`, it get it inside the curly brackets

```
payloadArgs = $"{payload.ToString().Replace("\n", "; ")}TrackingID: \"{trackingId}\"";
```

Comment: Probably it worth specifying what exactly was wrong

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy added an explanation.